# How do I find the config files for any application

Tags: configuration

I ran into this problem multiple times now.

You have to log into a server you don't know and have to find where an application is installed and where its config files are.

I know that most application configs are in `/etc/`... e.g. `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`

But knowing is not reliable. How can I find them guaranteed?

And what is a good way to inspect and study the configs? Most applications allow for other files to be included so the configuration can be split into multiple files which takes ages to write down all the files' locations and look at all of them individually which gets even worse if the structure is cascading.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! A good number of man pages have a `FILES` section, which usually includes the list of paths/descriptions of the relevant configuration files. Are you specifically thinking about poorly documented applications?

Comment: many do not list anything... and then many do not have a man page either

Answer (score 2):

Here's a universal method for Linux. Install `strace` and do this:

```
sudo strace -e file -fF -o /tmp/application.log application
```

You can then examine `/tmp/application.log` and see all the open files. If the app uses files from `/etc` you can `grep /etc /tmp/application.log`.

The use of `sudo` above is required only for system-wide daemons/services.

Comment: This requires you to actually RUN this untrusted application. If it does its "Bad Things" on 1st execution...

Comment: `-F` is deprecated. From the man page:        
```-F          This  option  is  deprecated.   It is retained for backward
compatibility only and may be removed in  future  releases.
Usage  of  multiple instances of -F option is still equiva‐
lent to a single -f, and it is ignored at all if used along
with one or more instances of -f option.```

Comment: @JonasStein there's no harm in specifying it and it will work for e.g. CentOS 6 users. You're welcome to edit the answer if you absolutely feel like `-F` must be removed. Some answers here are now more than a decade old thus they are bound to become outdated. Software changes fast.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is list the content of the software package. Most configuration file(s) on Linux are in `/etc/`. So you can do something like this:

On Arch Linux:

```
pkgfile <package name> | grep etc
```

For an AUR package, you do a tar of the built TAR file, e.g.

```
tar tvf ~/.cache/yay/<package name>/<package name and version>.tar.xz | grep etc
```

On Debian / Ubuntu / Linux Mint:

```
apt-file <package name> | grep etc
```

And you can find similar CLI command for other Linux distributions.

And as an added bonus, you **know exactly** where all files are installed for a given package.

Comment: 1) It's arch specific 2) it will not work for any software installed outside of arch ports 3) the debian advice will fail to work if configuration files are not stored in `/etc` and there are applications/daemons/services which uses file from `/usr`, `/opt`, `/usr/local` or even `/var`.

Comment: Well, I gave the answer as an example. You can "grep config" instead of "grep etc". And I am not going to list all similar commands for other Linux distributions. If you know, you can add similar command for RedHat or Slack, for example.

Comment: OMG!! apt-file is the missing package file locator I've been searching for! It even does reverse search (find package from file: https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file). IMO, this should be installed default on any *nix system, as compared to Windows where all files are in a single directory. Unfortunately, it doesnt work for Snaps, but there is a wish list for that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257724/how-to-search-all-snap-packages-for-filename ..actually, `dpkg --listfiles <pkg>` or `dpkg -S <file>` does both these and also works on Snaps.

Comment: One caveat is neither of these show the user conf files, officially supposed to be located in ~/.config or ~/.local/.. per Freedesktop standardization, but end up in places like ~/.mozilla, ~.vimrc, etc..

Answer (score -1):

Each application developer has to choose for herself where configuration files for that application are stored. Is it a per-user config? Is it a system-wide config?

One can find the configuration file - it's contained in the `application`.

```
strings $(type -p application)
```

Read `man strings` to optimize .

Comment: The `strings` approach is destinged to fail if the app concatenates strings or does anything to compute where its files are. Also, how would you know which strings are the ones which pertain to configuration files and which are not? `strace` on the other hand always shows *the exact opened files* and nothing else. Example `strings $(which smbd) | grep etc` -> returns nothing at all. At the same time `strings $(which smbd) | wc -l` -> 1281. Good luck with finding what is really used.

Comment: What does `which smbd` return on your system? Why do you assume configuration files have "`etc`" in their pathnames? Pipe the output into `less`, page through, and scan by eye. Non-junk text really stands out.

Comment: Why would a FOSS (Free Open Source Software) application obfuscate the location of a configuration file, when we can just read the source?

Comment: Which part of `strings $(which smbd) | wc -l` -> 1281 you haven't noticed? The f it matters what `which smbd` returns on my system? Again, stop talking crap: `strings` will **not** allow you to understand which files are actually used, it takes **a huge amount of time** to sift through and it's generally a bad piece of advice.

Comment: `stat $(which smbd)
  File: /usr/sbin/smbd
  Size: 111264     Blocks: 224        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 815h/2069d Inode: 812206      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:smbd_exec_t:s0
Access: 2021-04-07 19:17:57.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2021-04-07 19:17:57.000000000 +0000
Change: 2021-04-17 11:33:26.181150440 +0000
 Birth: 2021-04-17 11:33:26.180150450 +0000`

Comment: And what if the location of configuration files is **not** stored in the main executable? My advice will work regardless, yours will fail miserably.